# How to find spanning tree of a graph that minimizes the maximum edge weight?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, spanning-trees

Suppose we have a graph G. How can we find a spanning tree that minimizes the maximum weight of all the edges in the tree? I am convinced that by simply finding an MST of G would suffice, but I am having a lot of trouble proving that my idea is actually correct. Can anyone show me a proof sketch or give me some hints as to how to construct the proof? Thanks!

Comment: Try to construct a counterexample. Not sure that one exists, but for a moment I felt that one does. In any case, this is a good _proof strategy_.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree

Comment: ahh so my intuition was correct. Thank you Jukka Suomela!

Comment: Mine failed me.

Comment: just goes to show how unreliable intuitions are. but sadly my mind can't think rigorously enough so that i still have to rely on my intuitions sometimes.

Comment: If you know Kruskal’s algorithm for the minimum spanning tree, it is an easy exercise to show that the output of Kruskal’s algorithm is a minimum bottleneck spanning tree.  (I think that it is easier than showing that the output of Kruskal’s algorithm is a minimum spanning tree.)

Comment: actually, a simple exchange argument would suffice without necessarily having to appeal to Kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: @AdenDong if you solved your own question, [feel free to self-answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @AdenDong: The more rigorous facts you know the more intuition you need to manage them. Intuition is a *good* thing, after it has been shaped by experience to be right more often than not.

Comment: @DaveClarke: "In any case, this is a good proof strategy." -- True. [Worked for me](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2211/98). TCS/maths education should focus way more on this back and forth that is inherent to the process.

Comment: [More recent duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4942).

Comment: Note that this can be done in linear time (faster than finding an MST).  The basic idea is to binary search for the minimum K such that deleting edges of cost more than K leaves the graph connected.  In addition, when you query a K and determine that it is big enough, you delete all edges of cost greater than K.  When you query a K and determine it is too small, you contract all edges that have cost at most K.  (You use median finding on the remaining edge costs to find the K to query.)

Answer (score 5):

*What follows is taken from [Tsuyoshi Ito](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/568/tsuyoshi-ito)'s comment.*

If you know Kruskal’s algorithm for the minimum spanning tree, it is an easy exercise to show that the output of Kruskal’s algorithm is a minimum bottleneck spanning tree. (I think that it is easier than showing that the output of Kruskal’s algorithm is a minimum spanning tree.)

Answer (score 2):

Given a graph $G(V, A)$, we know that any spanning tree contains an edge in every cutset. Let  $S_{min}^{max}$ and $S$ be the minimax weight spanning tree of $G$ and minimum weight spanning tree of $G$ resp. Any edge $e \in S$ is associated with a cutset $C$. Corresponding to cutset $C$,$S_{min}^{max}$ must also contain an edge, say $e'$. Then if $w(e') < w(e)$, we know that replacing $e$ with $e'$ in $S$ will produce a new spanning tree with lower overall weight, thus contradicting our assumption of optimality of $S$. Hence, we can see that the weight of every edge in $S$ is no greater than the weight of a corresponding edge (obtained from the cutset) in $S_{min}^{max}$. Since, we have compared every edge in $S$ but perhaps possibly may not have compared every edge of $S_{min}^{max}$ in the above process for comparison, the max weight edge in $S_{min}^{max}$ has to be atleast as much as much as the max weight in $S$. Hence we can conclude that $S$ itself produces a minimax weight spanning tree.