# Mimimum spanning tree with a constraint on number of certain types of edges

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms, weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, constraint-satisfaction

I have the the following problem.

Say we have a graph $G = (V,E)$ where all $e \in E$ have positive weight, and $E$ can be separated in to two disjoint sets $E = A \cup B$. We have to find a spanning tree such that we minimize total weight but also we can only use a maximum of $c$ edges in $B$.

I feel like this is just Prim/Kruskal with an additional condition in the main if condition, but is that correct? I think we can still use a greedy algorithm but do not know how to show correctness.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us take [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) for an example. Apparently, OP refers to the adjusted version such that when we choose among edges of equal weight, we will pick the ones in $A$ before the ones in $B$ as long as at least one edge in $A$ is left available. If the MST we arrive in the end has no more than $c$ edges in $B$, then that MST is the output. Otherwise, the output is empty, indicating no such MST has been found. Let us name this algorithm **$A$-favoured Kruskal's algorithm**.

To prove that **$A$-favoured Kruskal's algorithm will find a satisfying MST whenever there is one** is, in fact, not trivial even if we have been enlightened with or especially when we are distracted by [the  general techniques on how to prove greedy algorithm is correct](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/91753).

Here goes my proof. Let us fix the weighted graph $G$ so that we will often be referring to $G$ implicitly. Let $R$ be a particular run of Kruskal's algorithm that produces $m$, an MST. Let $RA$ be a particular run of $A$-favoured Kruskal's algorithm that produce $ma$, another MST. ($RA$ may or may not be the same as $A$ and $ma$ may or may not be the same as $m$). Suppose $w_1\lt w_2\lt\cdots$ is the increasing sequence of all distinct edge weights. Break up the while loop of $R$ into smaller loops $R_1\lt R_2\lt\cdots$. For each $i$, $R_i$ iterates over all edges of weight $w_i$. For each such edge, $R_i$ adds it to the growing forest if it connects two different trees and ignores it otherwise. Let $F_i$ be the forest obtained at the end of $R_i$. Let $E_0=G$. For $i\gt0$, let graph $E_i$ has the same vertices as $G$  and all edges of $G$ except the edges of weights greater than $w_i$.

Using induction on $i > 0$, we can see that each connected component of $F_i$ (, which is a tree) is its corresponding connected component of $E_i$ minus some edges (the edges that were discarded because they did not connect different connected components(trees)). Let $g_i$ be the number of edges in $A$ of weight $w_i$ that are selected into $m$ during $R_i$. We can see that $g_i$ cannot bigger than $h_i$, the largest number of edges in $A$ of weight $w_i$ that can be added to $H_{i-1}$ without causing a cycle. In fact, $h_i$ is the decrease from the number of connected components in $E_{i-1}$ to the number of connected components in $E_{i-1}$ with all edges in $A$ of weight $w_i$ added. So $h_i$ depends only on $G$, $A$ and $i$. Note that $g_i$ will be $h_i$ if $R$ is actually a run of $A$-favoured Kruskal's algorithm, such as $RA$. So 
$$\#\{\text{edges in } A \text{ and } m\} = \sum_{i}g_i
\leq \sum_{i}h_i = \#\{\text{edges in } A \text{ and } ma\}$$

Note that all MSTs can be found by Kruskal's algorithm. For a proof, you can check [any MST is reachable by any MST algorithm with some minor exceptions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95625/91753). So we have shown that of all MSTs, $ma$ has the most edges in $A$. Since the number of edges in $ma$ is the same, $ma$ has the least edges in $B$. Proof is completed.

Indeed, we have proved more. **Any run of $A$-favoured Kruskal's algorithm will produce an MST with the same number of edges with any given weight in $A$ and in $B$**.

Comment: Another proof could use [selection by weight reduction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33799/91753)