# How to obtain edge set that containing the widest path from s to t by partitioning and searching?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis

**Problem.** To obtain a path from vertex s to vertex t whose minimum-weight edge must be the maximum one among the ones of all the paths from s to t. This path is just the bottle-neck path from s to t.

The following is my algorithm for finding bottle-neck path by sub-ranges searching. Actually I just want to get the smallest set that containing the widest path from s to t.

In the algorithm, searching is for the subset that contains path from s to t. The steps make sure the smallest edge in the result subset belongs to the widest path from s to t.

Suppose variables as the following.

$m$ -- the number of total edges.

$E_i$ -- the set which does not contain path from s to t at the $i_{th}$, while for all edges in $E_i$, the weight is bigger than or equal to the maximum minimum-weight edge in all s-t paths. $E_0$ is empty.

$T_i$ -- the set which is a sub-range that contain the maximum minimum-weight edge. We need to partition it into sub-ranges.

$k_i$ -- the number of sub-ranges at the $i_{th}$ recursion. It’s calculated out in **Step 1**.

**Steps.**

**Step 1 -** If $Size(T_i) = 1$ then the algorithm stops. Else $k_i = f(Size(T_i))$.

> $f(Size(T_i))$ is a function whose argument is $Size(T_i)$. I am not sure what it should be.

**Step 2 -** Partition $T_i$ into $k_i$ descending sub-ranges. We use $R_j$ to stand for the $j_{th}$ sub-range whose weight of edges are only smaller than the ones in $j-1$ sub-ranges before it.

> Partition is done by Fibonacci Heap. We **don't** need edges in one sub-set keep in order.

**Step 3 -** Let $Total = E_i$.

**Step 4 -** Repeat. Get sub-range $R_j$ from $k_i$ sub-ranges in descending order. ($k_i$ times at most)

- $Total = Total + R_j$
- If there is a path from s to t in $Total$(its cost is $O(m)$),

  > *we know that $Total$ contains the biggest minimum-weight edge.*

  - $E_{i+1} = Total - R_j$.
  - $T_{i+1} = R_j$.

    > *In the next recursion, $R_j$ is partitioned to find a smaller set which
    >   containing the maximum minimum-weight edge.*
  - Go to **Step 1**.

    > Recursively increase $E_i$, and decrease $T_i$ and $k_i$. Until the $Size(T_i) = 1$.

After the algorithm stops, we get the target set $E_{i_{max}}$ containing all the edges which are bigger than or equal to the maximum minimum-weight edge. So the widest path from s to t is in $E_{i-{max}}$.

If set $f(Size(T_i)) = Size(T_i)/2$, on average, the final recursion time will be $i_{max} = log_2 m$.

**My question is that there should be a better $f(Size(T_i))$, what is it? And how to figure it out?**

Comment: Can you define what you mean by widest path?  What's the width of the path?  Actually, before you present your algorithm, can you first provide a specification of the algorithmic problem you are trying to state?

Comment: @D.W. You are right. I just modified it. Thanks!

Comment: If you exchange "minimum" for "maximum" and invert all other relations [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48063/6689) (e.g. exchanging "heaviest" with "lightest"), then it is related to your problem.

Comment: There is a simple $O((n+m)\log m)$ algorithm that does binary search on the edge weights and runs DFS at each step.