# Why if $G$ has two spanning trees $A$ and $A'$, then every edge of $A'\cup \{e_i\}\in A'$

Tags: proof-techniques, spanning-trees

> **Theorem**:
>
> Let be $G$ a weighted graph in which every edge has a different weight.
>
> Suppose that $G$ has two spanning trees $A$ and $A'$.
>   Let be $i$ the first index such that $e_i\ne e'_i$ and $i\ge 3$.
>
> Suppose that $w(e_i)<w(e'_i)$ and consider that $A' \cup \{e_i\}$ has a unique cycle.
>
> For each edge of this cycle then $w(e')<w(e_i)$ (else we would be able to create a tree $(A' \cup \{e_i\})\setminus\{e'\}$ of lower weight than $A'$, which contradicts the fact that $A'$ has minimal weight.
>
> *Therefore, every edge of this cycle must be in $A'$.* Which contradicts the fact that A is a tree

I don't understand the conclusion in italics. This a demonstration from my teacher but it seems that it pop out without any explanation... Can you help me?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352163/show-that-theres-a-minimum-spanning-tree-if-all-edges-have-different-costs)? [Here's another possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251206/can-two-minimum-spanning-trees-for-the-same-graph-have-different-edge-weights) on stackoverflow that is more extensive than the first one, and [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/do-the-minimum-spanning-trees-of-a-weighted-graph-have-the-same-number-of-edges/2211#2211) is a nice LaTeX version of the SO proof (I think).

Comment: Yes it is for the definition! Actually we have e and e' ut I don't know how todo it in Latex (the prime above e and not above the indice...)

Comment: @Marine1 Write `e'` ($e'$) rather than `e\prime` ($e\prime$). This works with subscripts, too: `e'_i` and `e_i'` both give $e'_i$, as distinct from `e_{i'}`, which gives $e_{i'}$.